# ¿ Cómo cambiar de activity en cada opcion de un ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un menú desplegable con unas determinadas opciones y sólo sé que a cada opción que haga click me lleve a una activity.. pero yo quiero que dependiendo la opción que pulse lleve a otra activity.... Seguí un tutorial pero solo muestra tal como es en el Main Activity, el los layout no sale nada , dejo aquí mi Main y como pongo el onClick pero está puesto a todos, yo quiero decidir qué activity sale dependiendo de qué opción elige el usuario:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListView expandableListView;

    List<String> langs;
    Map<String,List<String>>topics;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;


  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  expandableListView =(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
  fillData();

  listAdapter = new MyExListAdapter(this,langs,topics);
  expandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

  expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {


    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
            int childPosition, long id) {

        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, langs.get(groupPosition)+ ":" +topics.get(langs.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent siguiente = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Calculo.class);
        startActivity(siguiente);
        //return false;
        return false;
    }
});

} 

  public void Matematicas (View v){
      Intent siguiente = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Calculo.class);
        startActivity(siguiente);

  }

  public void fillData(){

      langs = new ArrayList<String>();
      topics = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

      langs.add("PRIMERO");
      langs.add("SEGUNDO");
      langs.add("TERCERO");
      langs.add("CUARTO");

      List<String> Primero = new ArrayList<String>();
      List<String> Segundo = new ArrayList<String>();
      List<String> Tercero = new ArrayList<String>();
      List<String> Cuarto = new ArrayList<String>();

      Primero.add("MATEMATICAS I");
      Primero.add("FISICA I");
      Primero.add("PROGRAMACIÓN");

      Segundo.add("ONDAS");
      Segundo.add("TCOM");


      Tercero.add("ENERGÍA");
      Tercero.add("DST");
      Tercero.add("FTRANS");

      Cuarto.add("C.ESPACIALES");
      Cuarto.add("C.DIGITALES");
      Cuarto.add("C.MÓVILES");


      topics.put(langs.get(0),Primero);
      topics.put(langs.get(1),Segundo);
      topics.put(langs.get(2),Tercero);
      topics.put(langs.get(3),Cuarto);

  }

}
```

Comment: Ahora agrego una respuesta, solo una pregunta, cada elemento quieres que realice un intent verdad?

Comment: Sí, exactamente, lo que yo quiero es agregar un intent diferente para cada elemento, no el mismo a todos

Comment: Porque solo conozco lo que está ahí, el: @Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,  int childPosition, long id) y eso engloba a TODOS, quiero poner algo para que dirigirme a cada elemento y asignarle un intent diferente sí

Comment: vale, espero respuesta, porque esto me supera jeje

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que tomar en cuenta que en un [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) puedes tener varios grupos, donde el indice definido es `groupPosition` y dentro de cada grupo varios "hijos" definidos por el indice `childPosition`.

Por ejemplo si defines que  quieres realizar un intent al dar click en el segundo elemento (indice 1) del primer grupo (indice 0), lo realizarías de esta forma dentro de onChildClick() :

```
 expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {


    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
            int childPosition, long id) {

       if(groupPosition == 0 && childPosition == 1){
             //Realiza el intent al dar click en el segundo elemento del primer grupo.
             Intent siguiente = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Calculo.class);
             startActivity(siguiente);
       }

        //return false;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Elena, veo que controlas mucho este tema, puedes echarle por favor un vistazo a mi ultima pregunta a ver si puedes ayudarme? Esta respuesta no la he podido probar aún pero tiene buena pinta. Respecto a mi última pregunta es como poner unas pestañas secundarias debajo de otras pestañas que tengo ya creadas.